# Calculate the length of shared boundaries between multiple polygons

Tags: r, gis, polygon, shapefile

I have a shapefile and I want to know for each polygon what other polygons touch it. To that end I have this code:

```
require("rgdal")  
require("rgeos")

download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbxx9dic34qwz63/Polygons.zip?dl=1", "Polygons.zip")

Shapefile <- readOGR(".","Polygons")

Touching_List <- gTouches(Shapefile, byid = TRUE, returnDense=FALSE)

Touching_DF <- setNames(stack(lapply(Touching_List, as.character)), c("TOUCHING", "ORIGIN"))
```

I now want to go further and understand the extent to which each polygon touch other polygons. What I am after for each row in `Touching_DF` is a total length/perimeter for each `ORIGIN` polygon and the total length that each `TOUCHING` polygon is touching the origin polygon. This will then allow the percentage of the shared boundary to be calculated. I can imagine the output of this would be 3 new columns in `Touching_DF` (e.g. for the first row it could be something like origin parameter 1000m, touching length 500m, shared boundary 50%). Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I have applied @StatnMap's answer to my real dataset. It appears that `gTouches` is returning results if a polygon shares both an edge and a point. These points are causing issues because they have no length. I have modified StatnMap's portion of code to deal with it, but when it comes to creating the data frame at the end there is a mismatch between how many shared edges/vertices gTouches returns and how many edges have lengths.

Here is some code to demonstrate the problem using a sample of my actual dataset:

```
library(rgdal)  
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(raster)

download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/hsnrdfthut6klqn/Sample.zip?dl=1", "Sample.zip")

unzip("Sample.zip")
Shapefile <- readOGR(".","Sample")

Touching_List <- gTouches(Shapefile, byid = TRUE, returnDense=FALSE)

# ---- Calculate perimeters of all polygons ----
perimeters <- sp::SpatialLinesLengths(as(Shapefile, "SpatialLines"))

# ---- All in a lapply loop ----
all.length.list <- lapply(1:length(Touching_List), function(from) {
  lines <- rgeos::gIntersection(Shapefile[from,], Shapefile[Touching_List[[from]],], byid = TRUE)
  if(class(lines) != "SpatialLines"){lines <- lines@lineobj}
  l_lines <- sp::SpatialLinesLengths(lines, longlat=FALSE)
  results <- data.frame(origin = from,
                    perimeter = perimeters[from],
                    touching = Touching_List[[from]],
                    t.length = l_lines,
                    t.pc = 100*l_lines/perimeters[from])
  results
})
```

This specifically shows the issue for one of the polygons:

```
from <- 4
lines <- rgeos::gIntersection(Shapefile[from,], Shapefile[Touching_List[[from]],], byid = TRUE)
if(class(lines) != "SpatialLines"){lines <- lines@lineobj}
l_lines <- sp::SpatialLinesLengths(lines, longlat=FALSE)

plot(Shapefile[c(from, Touching_List[[from]]),])
plot(lines, add = TRUE, col = 1 + 1:length(Touching_List[[from]]), lwd = 2)
```

The two possible solutions I see are 1. getting gTouches to return only shared edges with a length greater than zero or 2. returning a length of zero (rather than error) when a point rather than an edge is encountered. So far I can't find anything that will do either of these things.

**EDIT 2**

@StatnMap's revised solution works great. However, if a polygon does not share a snapped boarder with its neighbouring polygon (i.e. it goes to a point and then creates an island slither polygon) then it comes up with this error after `lines <- rgeos::gIntersection(Shapefile[from,], Shapefile[Touching_List[[from]],], byid = TRUE)`

```
   Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, unaryUnion_if_byid_false,  : 
      Geometry collections may not contain other geometry collections
```

I have been looking for a solution that is able to identify polygons with badly drawn borders and not perform any calculations and return 'NA' in `res` (so they can still be identified later). However, I have been unable to find a command that distinguishes these problematic polygons from 'normal' polygons.

Running @StatnMap's revised solution with these 8 polygons demonstrates the issue:

```
download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttg2mi2nq1gbbrq/Bad_Polygon.zip?dl=1", "Bad_Polygon.zip")
unzip("Bad_Polygon.zip")
Shapefile <- readOGR(".","Bad_Polygon")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to Sébastien Rochette answer, I think function `st_length` from `sf`package does not work with polygons (see this [post](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/268)). Instead I suggest using function `st_perimeter` in `lwgeom` package.

(I wanted to comment the answer but I don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 11):

The intersection of two polygons only touching themselves is a line. Calculating a line length is easy with functions of spatial libraries in R.
As you started your example with library `sp`, you'll find a proposition with this library. However, I also give you a proposition with the new library `sf`.

## Calculate polygons shared boundaries lengths with library `sp`

```
require("rgdal")  
require("rgeos")
library(sp)
library(raster)

download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbxx9dic34qwz63/Polygons.zip?dl=1", "Polygons.zip")

unzip("Polygons.zip")
Shapefile <- readOGR(".","Polygons")

Touching_List <- gTouches(Shapefile, byid = TRUE, returnDense=FALSE)

# Touching_DF <- setNames(utils::stack(lapply(Touching_List, as.character)), c("TOUCHING", "ORIGIN"))

# ---- Calculate perimeters of all polygons ----
perimeters <- sp::SpatialLinesLengths(as(Shapefile, "SpatialLines"))

# ---- Example with the first object of the list and first neighbor ----
from <- 1
to <- 1
line <- rgeos::gIntersection(Shapefile[from,], Shapefile[Touching_List[[from]][to],])
l_line <- sp::SpatialLinesLengths(line)

plot(Shapefile[c(from, Touching_List[[from]][to]),])
plot(line, add = TRUE, col = "red", lwd = 2)

# ---- Example with the first object of the list and all neighbors ----
from <- 1
lines <- rgeos::gIntersection(Shapefile[from,], Shapefile[Touching_List[[from]],], byid = TRUE)
l_lines <- sp::SpatialLinesLengths(lines)

plot(Shapefile[c(from, Touching_List[[from]]),])
plot(lines, add = TRUE, col = 1 + 1:length(Touching_List[[from]]), lwd = 2)
```

[image: Common frontiers as SpatialLines]

```
# ---- All in a lapply loop ----
all.length.list <- lapply(1:length(Touching_List), function(from) {
  lines <- rgeos::gIntersection(Shapefile[from,], Shapefile[Touching_List[[from]],], byid = TRUE)
  l_lines <- sp::SpatialLinesLengths(lines)
  res <- data.frame(origin = from,
                    perimeter = perimeters[from],
                    touching = Touching_List[[from]],
                    t.length = l_lines,
                    t.pc = 100*l_lines/perimeters[from])
  res
})

# ---- Retrieve as a dataframe ----
all.length.df <- do.call("rbind", all.length.list)
```

[image: Output table]

In the table above, `t.length` is the touching length and `t.pc` is the touching percentage with regards to the perimeter of the polygon of origin.

## Edit: Some shared boundaries are points (with `sp`)

As commented, some frontiers may be a unique point instead of lines. To account for this case, I suggest to double the coordinates of the point to create a line of length=0. This requires to calculate intersections with other polygons one by one, when this case appear.
For a single polygon, we can test this:

```
# Example with the first object of the list and all neighbours
from <- 4
lines <- rgeos::gIntersection(Shapefile[from,], Shapefile[Touching_List[[from]],], byid = TRUE)
# If lines and points, need to do it one by one to find the point
if (class(lines) == "SpatialCollections") {
  list.Lines <- lapply(1:length(Touching_List[[from]]), function(to) {
    line.single <- rgeos::gIntersection(Shapefile[from,], Shapefile[Touching_List[[from]][to],])
    if (class(line.single) == "SpatialPoints") {
      # Double the point to create a line
      L1 <- rbind(line.single@coords, line.single@coords)
      rownames(L1) <- letters[1:2]
      Sl1 <- Line(L1)
      Lines.single <- Lines(list(Sl1), ID = as.character(to))
    } else if (class(line.single) == "SpatialLines") {
      Lines.single <- line.single@lines[[1]]
      Lines.single@ID <- as.character(to)
    }
    Lines.single
  })
  lines <- SpatialLines(list.Lines)
}

l_lines <- sp::SpatialLinesLengths(lines)

plot(Shapefile[c(from, Touching_List[[from]]),])
plot(lines, add = TRUE, col = 1 + 1:length(Touching_List[[from]]), lwd = 2)
```

For all in a lapply loop:

```
# Corrected for point outputs: All in a lapply loop
all.length.list <- lapply(1:length(Touching_List), function(from) {
  lines <- rgeos::gIntersection(Shapefile[from,], Shapefile[Touching_List[[from]],], byid = TRUE)
  if (class(lines) == "SpatialCollections") {
    list.Lines <- lapply(1:length(Touching_List[[from]]), function(to) {
      line.single <- rgeos::gIntersection(Shapefile[from,], Shapefile[Touching_List[[from]][to],])
      if (class(line.single) == "SpatialPoints") {
        # Double the point to create a line
        L1 <- rbind(line.single@coords, line.single@coords)
        rownames(L1) <- letters[1:2]
        Sl1 <- Line(L1)
        Lines.single <- Lines(list(Sl1), ID = as.character(to))
      } else if (class(line.single) == "SpatialLines") {
        Lines.single <- line.single@lines[[1]]
        Lines.single@ID <- as.character(to)
      }
      Lines.single
    })
    lines <- SpatialLines(list.Lines)
  }
  l_lines <- sp::SpatialLinesLengths(lines)
  res <- data.frame(origin = from,
                    perimeter = perimeters[from],
                    touching = Touching_List[[from]],
                    t.length = l_lines,
                    t.pc = 100*l_lines/perimeters[from])
  res
})

all.length.df <- do.call("rbind", all.length.list)
```

This may also be applied with library `sf`, but as you apparently chose to work with `sp`, I won't update the code for this part. Maybe later...

*---- End of Edit ----*

## Calculate polygons shared boundaries lengths with library `sf`

Figures and outputs are the same.

```
library(sf)
Shapefile.sf <- st_read(".","Polygons")

# ---- Touching list ----
Touching_List <- st_touches(Shapefile.sf)
# ---- Polygons perimeters ----
perimeters <- st_length(Shapefile.sf)

# ---- Example with the first object of the list and first neighbour ----
from <- 1
to <- 1
line <- st_intersection(Shapefile.sf[from,], Shapefile.sf[Touching_List[[from]][to],])
l_line <- st_length(line)

plot(Shapefile.sf[c(from, Touching_List[[from]][to]),])
plot(line, add = TRUE, col = "red", lwd = 2)

# ---- Example with the first object of the list and all neighbours ----
from <- 1
lines <- st_intersection(Shapefile.sf[from,], Shapefile.sf[Touching_List[[from]],])
lines <- st_cast(lines) # In case of multiple geometries (ex. from=71)
l_lines <- st_length(lines)

plot(Shapefile.sf[c(from, Touching_List[[from]]),])
plot(lines, add = TRUE, col = 1:length(Touching_List[[from]]), lwd = 2)

# ---- All in a lapply loop ----
all.length.list <- lapply(1:length(Touching_List), function(from) {
  lines <- st_intersection(Shapefile.sf[from,], Shapefile.sf[Touching_List[[from]],])
  lines <- st_cast(lines) # In case of multiple geometries
  l_lines <- st_length(lines)
  res <- data.frame(origin = from,
                    perimeter = as.vector(perimeters[from]),
                    touching = Touching_List[[from]],
                    t.length = as.vector(l_lines),
                    t.pc = as.vector(100*l_lines/perimeters[from]))
  res
})

# ---- Retrieve as dataframe ----
all.length.df <- do.call("rbind", all.length.list)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Based on my sample data it does exactly what I am after. However, I have applied your solution to my 'real' dataset and have encountered some problems. I have edited my question to show what I mean.

Comment: Thanks. Your code works perfectly. The only issue I now have is with some of my input polygons being badly drawn. I can't do anything about this so I need to find a solution that either skips dodgy polygons (i.e. returns NA in res) or can cope with slither island polygons. The first option seems a better solution to me, I just can't find an if statement before 'rgeos::gIntersection(Shapefile[n,], Shapefile[Touching_List[[n]],], byid = TRUE)' that would be able to identify problem polygons. I have added a small set of 8 polygons to my question to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: Use a `try` or `tryCatch` and if `lines` returns an error, do the polygon by polygon approach of the `if` statement, with a another `try` inside.